# I need to sort games in an array using title, developer, genre, etc

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, search, printing

I am not sure how to do much with arrays yet and can't figure this out. Here is the full assignment.

1. Write a JAVA program that maintains a list of computer games using an array. Your main program should display the following menu repeatedly.

i. insert game

s. search game

p. print list

q. Quit

Select:

The array stores a list of computer games and each game in the list consists of title(string, key), developer(string), genre(string), year of production(int), and price(float). The list should be maintained in the increasing order of the key(title).

Option i should read a game(title, developer, genre, year, price) and insert the game into the array.  Note that the new game should be inserted into the right spot so that the entire array may remain sorted. Sorting entire array again after adding the new game at the end of the array is costly and hence not acceptable.  Option s asks for a game title and lists all the games matching with the title entered.  Note that two or more games may have the same title.  Option p simply lists all the games stored in the array.

We will assume a maximum of 100 games.

And here is what I have so far

package lab12;

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

  // create second class to hold methods
class next {

// create "insert game" method
public void insert( ) {
    System.out.println("Insert");

}

// create "search game" method
public void search( ) {
    System.out.println("Search");

}

// create "print list" method
public void print( ) {
    System.out.println("Print");

}

// create method to 

  }

 public class Lab12 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );

    // create string to see what user wishes to do
    String choose;

    // create instance of other class
    next choice = new next();

    do {
        // see which method user wants to use
    System.out.print("Do you want to insert game (i) or search game (s) "
            + "or print list (p) or quit (q)? ");
    // create string to see which method to go to
    choose = in.nextLine();

    // send user to correct method
    if ( choose.equals("i") || choose.equals("I"))
        choice.insert();
    else if ( choose.equals("s") || choose.equals("S") )
        choice.search();
    else if ( choose.equals("p") || choose.equals("P") )
        choice.print();

    } while ( choose.equals("i") || choose.equals("s") || choose.equals("p") 
            || choose.equals("I") || choose.equals("S") || choose.equals("P"));

  }

 }
```

I'm not sure how to sort the games in the array, it says to sort it by key but I don't know how to put in the key with the string. I'm not good with arrays either so I don't know how you can have all of the information linked together.
Thank you for all of your help!
Sincerely,
A stressed out college student.

Comment: Use some form of `Map` if you need a key, value pairing

Comment: Try to implement the methods before asking for help so that we may guide you in the right direction, as of now there is no way to know what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Like Nimble Fungus stated, the first step is to create a Game class that will be your object representing games in your array.

If you're not concerned about efficiency, the Collections library had a built-in sorting method you can use.  If you do need to worry about efficiency (for example, a massive data set) you should look into implementing a more advanced sorting algorithm.  Although, I'm fairly certain Collections.sort implements Merge Sort, which should suffice in most situations.

To use Collections.sort on a datastructure containing objects, you must provide a Comparator in the method call:

```
Collections.sort(array, comparator);
```

For information on creating and using a comparator object, check out the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) .

Also, if you plan on only using this comparator once, I might recommend creating an anonymous class, rather than creating a whole new class in your project.  Here is the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) for creating and using anonymous classes.

One last point to mention is that rather than creating a new comparator, you could actually have your Game class *implement* Comparable which would allow you to define the natural ordering of your Game objects at their creation.

Answer (score 0):

John, create a POJO with all four parameters.
Sort the array or list on each insert using comparator. Use below link to know more .
[http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/)

Or u can even use sorted map with key as game name .